# Do we need the "expressions" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are [11 questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions) tagged [expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions) including one that is tagged only with that tag.

I wonder if this is too general a tag to be useful. What do others think?

And how should we tag [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3700/8) otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

I looked through the list of questions you linked to, and did not find a single one (well, except possibly [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/truncate-treeform-to-show-only-the-top)), where the [expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions) tag would serve any meaningful purpose. So, I think that indeed, this tag is too general to be useful. I also think that if at a later point there will emerge a need for some more specific expressions-related tag, this will become clear to us. As to the recent question you linked to, I would rather use the tag [semantics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics), and / or perhaps [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) for it. My two cents.

Answer (score 4):

'expressions' is too vague, period. I am all for removing this one. Perhaps a tag wiki could be written telling users not to use this one.

As to your second question: I believe this is a fine example of a question that could be labeled with a function name (If). We have [a meta going on](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/167/57) precisely about that type of question and I don't feel the last word has been said about it.

If not with 'If' this particular question could perhaps have been tagged with 'return-value'.